# Hiding SpannableString web address

Tags: android, hyperlink, spannablestring

I have a web address that I want to be displayed as just a single word that when clicked opens the web browser from my alertdialog. Everything is working fine except that right now the full web address is displayed. I do not know how to hide this. Here is the code in my java file.

```
Tv = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewH));
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("www.Google.com");
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    if (Tv != null) 
    {
        Tv.setText(s);
        Tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }
```

I have tried replacing the www.google.com with

```
<ahref="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

but this does not even compile. There must be some kind of input argument configuration of SpannableString that allows this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an url span by hand:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Link to Google");
s.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Or create it from html:

```
Spanned s = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>");
```

Comment: I tried the first option that you listed and the hyperlink is masked but the link does not pull up the web browser when clicked. What could the problem be?

Comment: I just tried your second option with fromHtml which has worked brilliantly. 

[Salute](http://i43.tinypic.com/2vct5hy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily. here is am example.

i have edited this solution in your question.

```
Tv = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewH));
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Google");

if (Tv != null) 
{
    Tv.setText(s);
text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com/"),0, 5, 0);

Tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
Tv.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

i hope u will be happy by this answer......

Comment: I tried this and the hyperlink is masked but the link does not pull up the web browser when clicked although the word responds to being clicked by briefly flickering. What could the problem be?

Comment: I think you forgot to add Internet Permission in your Manifest.xml file.                                                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>       try this.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my manifest file and the code now works. Its always good to learn more than one way to do something 

[Salute](http://i43.tinypic.com/2vct5hy.jpg)

Comment: I also went through this kind of problem my times.. By the way it was my pleasure to help you..  Thanks.